# very weird thing with Scroll function in useEffect react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have div that contains chat messages and I want it to scroll down to the latest message immediately after rendering.
so when I used scroll function on that div in useEffect it did not work but when I run it inside setTimeout it worked

```js
  useEffect(()=>{
            getConversation()//fetch the conversation
            setTimeout(() => {
                holder.current.scroll(0, holder.current.scrollHeight)          
            console.log('=====================>',holder.current.scrollHeight)

            }, 400);
    },[getConversation])
```

and what is really weird if I set the time to 200ms instead of 400ms it will not work

Comment: why are you using `setTimeout`

Comment: I think your getConverstion() method is taking a lot of time to execute, so when you add setTimeout() your previous function gets times to be executed and hence gives the desired result.

Comment: - i use settimeout cause it will not work instead

Comment: so what do you think I should do ,Rohit

Comment: `setTimeout` is pretty much always a code smell.  You need to run your function as a callback.  Trying to time the load on your connection won't translate for others' slower connections.

Answer (score 0):

The fetching and scrolling should be separated.

Fetching happens when the component is loaded first time.

Scrolling should happen when the content is loaded, and the page is not already scrolled to top, so scrolling should depend only on these two criteria, e.g:

```
  useEffect(()=>{
      getConversation() // <--- updates state 'conversations'
  },[ getConversation ]);

  useEffect(()=>{
      if( needsToScroll ){  // <-- check somehow if already top
          holder.current.scroll(...)
      }
  }, [ conversation ]);
```

The `needsToScroll` condition might be omitted, then the page tries to scroll on every change of `conversation`, which is probably not visible, not often and ok.

On the other hand, it might be necessary to omit the whole dependency (`[ conversation ]`), if you need to check if `holder.current` is available (on every render). Then `needsToScroll` can check both `holder.current` and `conversation`.